# Merging multiple csv files in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have around 100 csv files with common headers, which i want to merge. The headers are "Lat", "Long" and "value". I am trying to merge all the csv files such that the output would be

```
"Lat" "Lon" "Value1" "Value2"..."Value 100"
```

`Lat` and `Lon` columns are identical for all of the csv files. Merging two files is easy

```
merge(data.frame1, data.frame2, by=c('Lat','Lon'))
```

However, I tried the following code which didnt work:

```
file_list <- list.files(~/source)   
list_of_files <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)  
m1 <- merge_all(list_of_files, by=c("Lat","Lon"), all=TRUE)
```

which throws the error

```
Error in merge.data.frame(dfs[[1]], Recall(dfs[-1]), all = TRUE, sort = FALSE,  : 
  formal argument "all" matched by multiple actual arguments.
```

Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: `list.files(~/source)` is a syntax error.  `merge_all` doesn't come with the usual R installation; please tell us where it is.

Comment: merge_all comes with package reshape, and yes sorry with syntax...but in the program i used a correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Reduce`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) and the plain `merge`:

```
m1 <- Reduce(function(old, new) { merge(old, new, by=c('Lat','Lon')) }, list_of_files)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work as well but you haven't given us any data to work with.  I personally use dbaupp's way and am not sure which one is faster; however, I rarely get into big data so the Reduce method is just so much easier for me to work with that's the way I go (I'm releasing a new R package in a few months that has a function to do multimerge that's basically based on the same thinking as dbaupp's response).  If you're dealing with big data you may want to bench mark the two (PS I stole this from somewhere as I rarely think in loops to solve problems but can't cite where).

```
DF <- list_of_files[[1]][, c('lat', 'Lon')]
    for (.df in list_of_files) {
    DF <-merge(DF,.df,by=c('Lat', 'Lon'), all=T, suffixes=c("", ""))
}
DF
```

Comment: Thank you, both works fine, but for merging some csv files i get the error  "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :   names do not match previous names". I think this was beacuse of some bug in merge() function reported earlier.